# How to link an authenticated user to a formModel

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a small project that I am working on and I have a Model that deals with delivery Address.  I want to be able to set / update the user details on this form but i really not sure how to do that.

I tried to set a user on my Profile model as a OneoToOneField with User but that doesnt seem to work andf I get an error:

```
Exception Value:    
Cannot assign "<User: bill>": "Profile.user" must be a "User" instance.
```

Im not certain how to proceed.

My model is:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib import auth
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.conf import settings


# Create your models here.
class User(auth.models.User, auth.models.PermissionsMixin):

    def __str__(self):
        return "@{}".format(self.username)


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    houseNumber = models.CharField(max_length=150, default='')
    street = models.CharField(max_length=150, default='')
    suberb = models.CharField(max_length=150, default='')
    city = models.CharField(max_length=150, default='')
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=150, default='')

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

My view is:

```
class ProfileView(LoginRequiredMixin,FormView):
    template_name = 'profile_form.html'
    success = 'profile.html'
    form_class = ProfileForm

    # def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    #     context = super(ProfileView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    #     context['now'] = timezone.now()
    #     return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.created_by = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(initial=self.initial)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            profile = form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = User.objects.get(pk=request.user.pk)
            profile.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('profile_details', args=(post.id,)))
        print("test")
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

I was expecting that the user would be linked to the delivery address. How do I do that?

Some exception I get is as follows:

```
Internal Server Error: /accounts/profile/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\009028\Envs\mydjangoproject\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\009028\Envs\mydjangoproject\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\009028\Envs\mydjangoproject\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 124, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\009028\Envs\mydjangoproject\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\009028\Envs\mydjangoproject\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\mixins.py", line 52, in dispatch

    return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\009028\Envs\mydjangoproject\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 88, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\009028\Documents\django-projects\aurion\burger\accounts\views.py", line 40, in post
    profile.user = request.user
  File "C:\Users\009028\Envs\mydjangoproject\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 300, in __set__
    super().__set__(instance, value)
  File "C:\Users\009028\Envs\mydjangoproject\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 210, in __set__
    self.field.remote_field.model._meta.object_name,
ValueError: Cannot assign "<SimpleLazyObject: <User: bill>>": "Profile.user" must be a "User" instance.
[17/Apr/2019 16:12:05] "POST /accounts/profile/ HTTP/1.1" 500 97063
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just use **`request.user`** then you get **`current logged in user`**

```
profile = form.save(commit=False)
profile.user = request.user
profile.save()
```

**for debug can** **`print(request.user)`**

Comment: Hi @Sangram thanks for the quick response. If I do what you suggest I get the following ValueError: Cannot assign "<SimpleLazyObject: <User: bill>>": "Profile.user" must be a "User" instance.error:

Comment: Try this too  **`profile.instance.user = request.user`**

Comment: I printed off the response in the code after the line profile.user = request.user. But no request is printed and there is an error on the line :  profile.user = request.user

Comment: 'Profile' object has no attribute 'instance'

Comment: as per my knowledge there two ways 1. `profile.user = request.user` 2. `profile.instance.user = request.user`

Comment: hey @alasdair , see this issue please

Comment: I added the exception

Comment: What was the output of the debug statement print(request.user)?

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, there is a [signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/signals/) to create Profile when a user is created. You can put those signals in `signals.py` and import them when the App is ready. For example:

```
# assuming they are in apps_directory/profile/signals.py

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()

# apps.py
from django.apps import AppConfig
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class ProfilesConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'profiles'
    verbose_name = _('profiles')

    def ready(self):
        import apps_directory.profiles.signals
```

Now if you want to update the profile which is already created through signals, then you can use [UpdateView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#updateview):

```
class ProfileUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    template_name = 'profile_form.html'
    success = 'profile'
    model = Profile
    form_class = ProfileForm  # assuming its a modelform

    def get_object(self):
        return self.request.user.profile # we will get profile as it has onetoone relation to user model
```

Comment: Hi @ruddra I get this error:              profile.user = request.user ...
▼ Local vars
Variable Value
args 
()
form 
<ProfileForm bound=True, valid=True, fields=(houseNumber;street;suberb;city;phone)>
kwargs 
{}
profile 
<Profile: Profile object (None)>
request 
<WSGIRequest: POST '/accounts/profile/'>
self 
<accounts.views.ProfileView object at 0x00000299EF844908>

Comment: Let me create a new user first

Answer (score 0):

`request.user` is not an instance of your custom `User`, it's an instance of `django.contrib.auth.models.User`

Since you defined your own `User` model, you need to tell Django that this is model to use for authentication in the `settings.py`.

```
#settings.py
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.User'  #point to the app in whose model.py, User is defined
```